# error "socket.timeout: The read operation timed out" while installing a python module

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I was triying to install the large English module "en_core_web_lg" for spaCy (a library for Natural Language Processing)

For some reasons, the small and medium modules were successfully installed (with few errors at first),
but the large module always crashed installation.

I have used two different methods:

1)

```
$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

2)

`$ pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz`

But in both cases I always got these two Exceptions:

```
(venv) omar@omar-device:~/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/bin$ pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz (852.3MB)
    38% |████████████▎                   | 325.7MB 114kB/s eta 1:16:26Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 331, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 413, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 448, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 488, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 929, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 791, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 575, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 897, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 619, in _download_url
    consume(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 844, in consume
    deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 585, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/ui.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 574, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 465, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/omar/virtualenvironment/my_new_app/bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 336, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I tried to reinstall Python3 at first, but crashed my desktop and terminal and had to fix that using the console :D (using this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried many times in both system environment and virtual environment, and reached 100% of downloading once (~850MB), then it gave me that error again ! So, the problem obviously was not in the downloading step, but in the direct installation after it.

So I thought about splitting the two steps:
first download the module using:

```
$ wget "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz"
```

then install it using

```
$ pip install en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

and it worked smoothly.

It is true that I got around the original problem, but I still don't know what caused it to happen in the first place (if you knew, kindly write an answer for it).

Answer (score 11):

try increasing pip timeout: `pip install --default-timeout=900 [pkg_name]`